# Java thread method and block synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

1) If a class (say `TestClass`) has two methods (`method1`, `method2`). Two threads (`t1`, `t2`) are running parallely where `t1` is calling `method1` of an object `object1` (of type `TestClass`), and `t2` is calling `method2` of the same object (`object1`).

1. What happens if, only `method1` is synchronized, and `method2` is not?
2. If both methods are synchronized, then will both run parelley? (its not running, but why?, we can achieve this with two dummy objects and block level synchronization)
3. In the below, `method1` and `method2` of a same object can be executed parallely with two threads?

   ```
   void method1() {
     synchronized(object1) {
       ....
     }
   }

   void method2() {
     synchronized(object1) {
       ....
     }
   }
   ```
4. What is the usage of synchronized block with .class `synchronized(TestClass.class) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If only method1 is `synchronized`, then method2 and method1 can be executed in parallel.
2. If both methods are marked `synchronized` they cannot run in parallel.

I think what's confusing you here is the `synchronized` keyword.  A synchronized method will be synchronized for that instance of class.  Like so:

```
synchronized void Method1(){}
synchronized void Method2(){}
```

These methods can only be entered if the instance they're defined in is not being used to execute a synchronized block of code elsewhere.  Compare that to this:

```
void Method1(){
    //can run in parallel 
    synchronized(this){
        //cannot run in parallel.
    }
    //can run in parallel.
}
void Method2(){ 
    synchronized(this){
        //cannot run in parallel.
    }
}
```

This is not quite the same.  Both methods **can** be entered, but code within the synchronized block cannot run in parallel.

Lastly, if you synchronize on `TestClass.class` it will prevent code anywhere synchronizing on the same object from executing.  This is true when synchronizing on any static object.

Comment: Then when to use static object and when to use TestClass.class?

Comment: Using a static object, orusing TestClass.class serves the same purpose here.  You use either whenever you want to synchronize some static code among multiple threads.

Comment: Is there any place both serves differently?

Comment: No there's not, long as the static object was declared final.  If the static reference could be reassigned using TestClass.class would be a little different, but the basic idea remains the same.  Synchronize on TestClass.class, or a final static object when you need to synchronize access to shared static code.

Answer (score 0):

1. they can run concurrently
2. no, only one thread can have the lock of the object at a time. So, while one thread executes method1 or method2, no other trhread can execute any of these two methods on the same object.
3. no, since they both need to have the lock of the same object to execute
4. To prevent other threadd to execute static synchronized methods of the TestClass concurrently, or any block synchronizing on the same Class object.

Answer (score 0):

As long the methods do not change state of the/any object in common scope, there is no need to sync. The interessting part is in `....`.

Comment: I know what is sync, but I am confused when having multiple sync, and has got cleared now.